# How do I implement commutative (scalar) multiplication with a built-in type like `f64`?

Tags: rust

I'd like to implement a commutative scalar `f64` multiplication operation using the `*` operator. Implementing the `Mul<f64>` trait for my type gives me a right side multiplication like.

```
struct Foo(f64);

impl Mul<f64> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn mul(self, _rhs: f64) -> Foo {
        // implementation
    }
}

let a = Foo(1.23);
a * 3.45; // works
3.45 * a; // error: the trait bound `{float}: std::ops::Mul<Foo>` is not satisfied [E0277]
```

For a non-builtin scalar type, I can implement the same trait the other way round on the scalar, i.e. implementing `Mul<Foo>` on my scalar type.

How do I get a left side implementation for a built-in type like `f64` too?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply reverse your implementation, by swapping `f64` with `Foo`

```
impl std::ops::Mul<Foo> for f64 {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        rhs * self
    }
}
```

[Try it out in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d0ea8f3d509fa421b1d55d1bcc9e8d25&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I'm a bit struck, that you can implement a trait for built-in type not defined in your own crate. I thought that was impossible.

Comment: it's possible, because the trait you are implementing is generic and in this impl bound to your local type.